# Free the string member of a structure in C

Tags: c, free

I have a structure as follows:

```
struct something{
  char *string_member;

};
```

now I created

```
struct something *s = malloc(sizeof(struct something));

s.string_member = malloc(5); //one way
s.string_member = "some thing wrong"; // second way
```

While I free the memory pointed by s. How do I free the memory allocated to string_member in the both the cases. Do I have to worry about string_member in second case at all?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You mustn't free it in your `second way` example, and you have no way to (portably) make the difference between case one and case two by just looking at the pointer. So don't do that, make sure you always allocate the `string_member` using `malloc` or e.g. `strdup`. That way, you can always `free` it (once).

```
s.string_member = strdup("some thing wrong");  // the other way

...

free(s.string_member);
```

Answer (score 1):

In the first case, call `free(s.string_member)`. In the second case, you don't have to do anything. This is because the string is not dynamically allocated. The location where is resides is determined when the program is loaded, and any cleaning up for it is also done by the system.